# How to hide SQL queries from web browsers (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm new to this forum and have a dilemma with my MySQL/PHP site.  Now I've created a function that will pass a SQL query to it and execute it.  What I didn't account for was the fact my SQL query being passed to the function is showing up in the "view source" of all browsers; which is BIG security concern because hackers can see the query.  Here is a snippet of the function:

```
// connect to MySQL

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL". mysql_error());

// selects the database
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die("Couldn't select database"); 

function statement ($query)
{

    global $connection, $db;
    $sql = $query;
    $results = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    return $results;

}
```

Here's how its called:

```
$cat_results = statement("select * from $category");
```

Is there a way to hide the query passed from the browser using the function I have?  If not any recommendations on a better approach to this function?

Really appreciate any thoughts on this!!

Andre

Comment: There is nothing in the code provided that will output any query to the browser.  Can you provide more detail/code?

Comment: Certainly, I can show you what was outputted to the browsers "view source". Forgive the formatting!



<tr>
   <td><label>Category:</label></td>
   <td><select name="cat_add[]">
                     select * from `category`
     <option value='1'>top stories</option><option value='2'>business</option><option value='3'>entertainment</option><option value='4'>finance</option><option value='5'>lifestyle</option><option value='6'>science/health</option><option value='7'>sports</option>   <option value='8'>Tech</option><option value='9'>Blogs</option>                         </select></td>
</tr>

Comment: @Andre looks like a bug in your code.  short tags might be disabled or you might be doing somthing strange with mixed html/php tags.  Personally i only use php's print or a template system.  Mixed html and php makes me vomit.  (No joke)

Comment: @Rook, well I ensure that short tags were enabled, the thing is I'm using a local server setup for php.. so I'm not sure if I will see the same affect if I put it on a live server.  Thats something I will look at, personally using php prints makes it hard to see html code if you have it inline with php tags.  I chose the mixture so I can see the two clearer (color coding of code)..but to each their own!

Comment: @Rook, Right you are my friend about this bug, I would like to see an example of a template system..  Then maybe I can move away from this style of coding.

Answer (score 3):

First of all PHP isn't viewable by the client,  it is always executed by the server.  Second of all at no point can the client execute SQL on your server.  This is the basis of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  If you are building a query with JavaScript and then sending it a php script to be executed then you have a very serious vulnerability on your hands.

Comment: Exactly Rook, thats what I thought when dealing with PHP.  But apparently I see "select * from $category" in my browsers view source.  And no I'm not using JavaScript to build the query.

Answer (score 0):

it is not recommended to pass the query string all the way to the browser/client. you should only pass the query outcome to the client.

Comment: Well my intent was to display what comes from the resultset of the query to the client, which is happening.  In theory, the query pass should be hidden to the client as I'm not returning the query but the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you disable PHP on your server, or something breaks, your users won't ever see your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code should never show up in the html source.  When things are working properly it should all be processed by the server and only the results sent to the client.  Maybe you've missed a `<?` or `?>` tag somewhere that's preventing it from being seen as php?

Comment: Well I'm running a local server setup with WAMP ever heard of it?  I haven't tried on a live server yet as I'm still in the production phase.  I'm checking through my code to see if I encapsulated my PHP code within <? ?> tags.  But you think running it on a local server could be the issue?